# failed connection proceed to logout

Tags: php, odbc

I am trying to redirect to the logout page when the database connection fails. How do I do it? It always shows the error message but not the one I specify. Help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Richard

code:

```
function ms_connect() {
// Create connection
// Microsoft Access
$db_source = DB_SERVER;
$db_system = DB_SYSTEM_SEC; 
$odbc_driver = "driver={microsoft access driver (*.mdb)};dbq=" . $db_source . ";systemdb=" . $db_system; 


$conn = odbc_connect($odbc_driver, DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD); // Error returned here! 

        if ($conn) {
            return $conn;
        } else{
                exit("Connection could not be established.");
            header ("Location: /logout.php");
        }

}
```

it does not show "Connection could..."

```
error shown 
PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid account name or password., SQL state 08004 in SQLConnect in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\functions\functions.php on line 11
```

Comment: You need to hide php warnings. The header can't make changes once text has been put on screen.

Comment: how do you hide them?

Comment: Add 
"error_reporting(0);" at the start of your php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you see is triggered by the `odbc_connect` function, while it is strange that the `exit` string is not printed, it is not strange that your redirect does not work since the exit prevents it from being executed.

Try:

```
    if ($conn !== false) {
        return $conn;
    } else{

        header ("Location: /logout.php");
        exit();//just in case
    }
```

You can ignore the warning (and you should) by the connection using the '@' sign in front of the connect function. (which is more elegant than to ignore all errors).

```
$conn = @odbc_connect($odbc_driver, DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD); // Error returned here!
```

---

**edit**:
A nice way to do it and still show a message to the user plus redirect is using html meta redirects:

```
    if ($conn !== false) {
        return $conn;
    } else{

        echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=/logout.php" /></head><body>Could not create a connection, redirecting in 5 seconds.</body></html>';
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: This will give headers already send error :) You cant have any html before headers :) 

Functions that send/modify HTTP headers must be invoked before any output is made.

Comment: @MartinAndreev you are right, didn't think about that thanks. Changed the code.

Comment: ok, still won't work. let me rephrase, the user successfully logs in, (a session is created, redirect to page.php where the function is called. returns error, stays on page.php with the error. trying to log user off if any issue with connection. does redirect works this way?

Comment: think i managed to do it by @odbc_connect.... but can we show a message telling the user on the login page that the connection was not done?

Comment: You can also instead of modifying the header, echo an html redirect '<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/logout.php" /></head>'; which gets triggered after `x` (here 3) seconds.

Comment: sorry, don't understand... how am I modifying the header? the redirect now works and the logout page will redirect users back to the login page. But the user will be scratching their heads... not able to login, no  message!

Comment: with the header ("Location: /logout.php"); you modify the headers, therefor you cannot print any message before the redirect this way. When you print an html redirect though you do not directly modify the header and you can still print the message. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an exit, which will terminate the script before the redirect.
You can pass your error message as a get param and show it on your page if you need.

Your code should look like this :

```
if ($conn) {
        return $conn;
    } else{
        header ("Location: /logout.php?error=Connection+could+not+be+established.");
    }
```

Also if you want to hide the warning just add:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```